# configuring proxy service with 2 bindings in single wsdl

Tags: java, wsdl, osb

I need to implement a wsdl having 2 bindings and port types in oracle service bus(11g) proxy service for soap communication.
However,the proxy service gives an option of configuring only specific binding and port type.
Is there any option in osb,to implement/configure proxy service with 2 binding or no binding at all,so that ncoming request can be dynamically be attached to specific port type.
Is there any possibility to get binding information dynamically for any incoming request to osb.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps set up a proxy for each binding, then put an AnyXML proxy in front that looks up variables in `$inbound/ctx:transport` to route to the correct binding.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.But the proxy created by  AnyXML does not create an effective wsdl.Request coming to OSB needs wsdl based implementation.Is there any service type other than wsdl based that creates effective wsdl?

Comment: No, as far as I'm aware, only wsdl-based proxies expose `?wsdl`

Comment: So how can I implement wsdl based proxy service for both the ports so that client can dyamically bind to one of the ports.Client can only respond to wsdl based end point uri.